# Add CSS animation as Preloader to WordPress

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, customization, css

I found a CSS animation snippet on [Codepen](http://codepen.io/grayghostvisuals/pen/LEOjBG), and would like to add it in my WordPress site for preloader animation, but I couldn't find any related help or plugin that would allow me to add a Preloader with custom CSS animation.

I tried googling, but all I could find was plugins that accepts "GIF animation" for preloader animation. But, I want to use "CSS animation" instead of "GIF animation".

Any suggestions?

P.S. I only have a moderate knowledge of WordPress.

Comment: The linked codepen is just an animation, building a pre-loader would be a javascript/frontend task, not one specifically for WordPress. Do you mean to ask how to load javascript or stylesheets from your theme? Or place them inline?

Comment: No, All I could find on internet is the plugins which accepts "GIF animation" for preloaders, but I would like to use "CSS animation".

Comment: Plugin recommendations are off topic here, but you can ask how to build this ( rather than what to install ), can you be more specific about which parts you're unclear about? Are you asking how to implement a preloader? Do you know how but don't know how to load it in WordPress? Your questions ambiguous

Comment: I was just trying to add a preloader to my WordPress site with CSS animation(by any means). :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accomplish this by setting a class on the body and removing it with JS when the page is loaded. This is just a basic example but it'll work out of the box.

```
 // Add specific CSS class by filter
add_filter( 'body_class', 'my_class_names' );
function my_class_names( $classes ) {
    // add 'class-name' to the $classes array
    $classes[] = 'preloader-visible';
    // return the $classes array
    return $classes;
}

// Add preloader style
add_action('wp_head', function(){ ?>
  <style>
    /** let's every child  of body know there is a loader visible */
    body.preloader-visible {
      background:red;
    }

    /** by default loader is hidden */
    body > .loader {
       display:none;
    }

    /** when loader is active the loader will show */
    body.preloader-visible > .loader {
       display:block;
    }
  </style>
  <?php
});

// Remove preloader when document is ready
add_action('wp_footer', function(){ ?>
  <script>
    (function($){

      $(function () {

          $('body').removeClass('preloader-visible');

      });

    })(jQuery);
  </script>
  <?php
});
```