# Add Codepen animation as Preloader to WordPress

Tags: php, css, javascript, html

I found a CSS animation snippet on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/pawelqcm/pen/ObwyNe), and would like to add it in my WordPress site for preloader animation.

I have seen similar question being asked on [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/211781/add-css-animation-as-preloader-to-wordpress?newreg=9ff3287fa2974a779735a611ab79871c) , but I couldn't resolve this from the available information there. I want to know:

1) In which location should I add the codepen html code?

2) In which location should I add given CSS?

3) And in which location should I add any required JS to make it work like it happens [here](https://preview.themeforest.net/item/foodchow-a-food-ordering-or-hotel-directory-html-template/full_screen_preview/22333193?_ga=2.4886899.1733559858.1556337398-1844870033.1553953096)?

Answer (score 2):

> 1) In which location should I add the codepen html code?

If you're using a [child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/), then for example, you could copy parent theme `header.php` file to your child theme directory and add the required html to that file after `<head>`.

If you're developing your own theme, then put the markup wherever you want on.

Or you could also add the markup with an action hook (e.g. `wp_footer` or theme specific action hook, if available). This could be added to your theme's `functions.php` file or a [custom plugin file](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin). Something along these lines,

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'prefix_my_preloader' ); // or other suitable template hook
function prefix_my_preloader() {
  ?>
    <div id="cooking">
      <!-- rest of the markup -->
    </div>
  <?php
}
```

> 2) In which location should I add given CSS?

Styles can be added either to your (child) theme's `styles.css` file, Customizer's Additional css section (if available, but maybe not the best option), or a custom css file that is located either in your (child) theme or custom plugin directory. Remeber to [include the styles](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/) if you're using a custom css file.

> 3) And in which location should I add any required JS to make it work
>   like it happens here

Scripts can be added either to your (child) theme's `scripts.js` file or a custom js file that is located either in your (child) theme or custom plugin directory. Remeber to [include the scripts](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/) if you're using a custom js file.

**P.S**
You can also add the styles and scripts with custom functions using action hooks as mentioned on the accepted answer for [Add CSS animation as Preloader to WordPress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/211781/add-css-animation-as-preloader-to-wordpress?noredirect=1&lq=1). You would then add these functions either to your (child) theme's `functions.php` or a custom plugin file.

Comment: Adding something here, to achieve the expected behavior of preloader, you need to show it on page load and then hide/fadeout after page load completed. to do that you might want to use something like this. (this needs jquery), make sure your preloader have display:block in your css. this will override it when page load completes.

`<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$(window).on("load", function() {
preloaderFadeOutTime = 500;
function hidePreloader() {
var preloader = $('.spinner-wrapper');
preloader.fadeOut(preloaderFadeOutTime);
}
hidePreloader();
});
});
</script>`